# Minor upgrade using msi does not replace files

Tags: installshield

When I'm running a minor upgrade via msi, installation completed successfully, and in 'Programs and Features' I can see that the version is upgraded to the new version, BUT files are not replaced (they still have the old version).

I'm running minor upgrade via msi as followed:

```
msiexec /i project.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus /qn
```

When running the upgrade via setup.exe, everything is working fine. Files are replaced.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you remove "REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus?" I had just this problem last week. In the log I was seeing REMOVE=ALL even though I did not set that.

It might be beneficial to post your install log
msiexec /i project.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus /qn /l*v c:\pathToLog\installLog.txt

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the installation log file (typically located in %TEMP% directory and called MSIxxxxx.log? Find out what component the files not being updated, belong to, and see what the log says about that component. Also, make sure the component has a key file. If it does not, right-click on a file you want to be the key file in that component (in the Component view of InstallShield), and select "Set key file". If possible, select the key file that has updated version info.

Answer (score 0):

You might have not changed the assembly version and file version of the project.

I have faced the same issue.Even breakpoints wont work if you run the msi with the higher verison,but with the same assembly and file version.

By changing File and Assembly version of the project it works.

On every upgrade even assembly information needs to be changed along with setup version.